# how to find and replace a text into a pdf file using iText in

Tags: java, excel, pdf, itext

I have a pdf form, the structure is following

```
      Hello firstname,

      Mr. firstname you are currently working at the designation post 
      and your current package is salary.

      Thanks.

       Excel database
       --------------------------------------
      + firstname + salary   + designation  +  
      |-----------|----------|--------------|
      | Alin      | 3,00,000 | Manager      |
      | Roy       | 2,75,000 | Php Developer|
      +-----------+----------+--------------+
```

Here the keyword firstname,designation and salary is fetched from the **excel database** and change dynamically.
suppose if user select alin then in **pdf form in firstname is replace by Alin and salary and designation is replace by 3,00,000 and Manager respectively.**

My problem is that i am new in iText i can't find the way how to search and replace these keywords.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You have a PDF form, but you don't tell us which type: is it an AcroForm, an XFA form, or just a static PDF (in which case you don't have a form). Also: it is unclear if you're asking how to fetch data from Excel or how to fill out a PDF form. Please clarify!

Comment: As Bruno asks, what exactly do you have? And furthermore, how flexible are you in changing the requirements? E.g. if currently your *pdf form* actually is no form but a simple PDF with some in-text placeholders, would a replacement by an actual PDF form be possible?

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't consider iText as my preferred technology to do this.

I'd use a Velocity template for XSL-FO, populate it with dynamic data, generate XSL-FO, and turn that into a PDF using standard XSL-T engine.  Convoluted, but effective.

Or, if you wish to stick to the iText track, just figure out how to do the substitution in Java objects and generate the form that way.

I wouldn't recommend Excel as a "database".

Comment: Excel is not good but it is requirement of client. i am unaware about the XSL-FO. is it Open source.?

Comment: It's a W3C standard.  The XSL-T engine built into the JDK can turn it into a PDF for you.  As for Excel, you need smarter clients.

Comment: For somebody who is new to iText who doesn't understand how forms work, studying XSL:FO will be hell...

Comment: Agreed.  I'll point out to those who don't know, Bruno is the author of iText, so he might have a bias in favor of using his s/ware.  But he has a valid point here: XSL-FO is not my favorite.  (XSL-T in general is a terrible idea.)